# solving one equation with 2 unknowns to obtain a specific range of possible answers in R

Tags: r, math, linear-algebra, equation, equation-solving

Suppose in **equation (1)** below, `d = .99`. Also, `sd = 1.2`. Desirably, `5+(.1*5) <= m1 <= 5+(.5*5)`, and `5 <= m2 <= 5+(.3*5)`

**Equation (1):**     **`d = (m1-m2) / sd`**

## Question

There surely are ***many*** possible answers for `m1` and `m2`. But **in R**, how can I obtain *the* possible answers for `m1` and `m2` that fall within the range of `m1` and `m2` that I specified above (This is why I used "*Desirably*" above)?

Comment: If the answer is underdetermined as you seem to imply then there are an infinite number of possible solutions. Plotting the define equalities my be helpful. Unfortunately, your inequality limits have no dependence on any variable.

Comment: @42-, thanks for your insight. If I may, could you probably provide a short response showing how to implement your approach?

Comment: Only if you make the limits for the inequalities depend on a variable would it make sense to me. At the moment it looks like the m1 and m2 variable are in a rectangular box. Rather trivial. The connection between 'sd' and 'mean' is completely unclear.

Comment: @42-, what may be the characteristics of the variable that the limits for the inequalities could depend on? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving your equation for `m1` yields that `m1 = m2 + d*sd`, so:

```
m1 = m2 + 1.188
```

Your inequalities are

```
5.5 <= m1 <= 7.5
5.0 <= m2 <= 6.5
```

If we replace `m1` in the first inequality by `m2 + 1.188` and simplify, we get the two inequalities:

```
4.312 <= m2 <= 6.312
  5.0 <= m2 <= 6.5
```

To have them both true we need

```
max(4.312,5.0) <= m2 <= min(6.312,6.5)
```

so:

```
5.0 <= m2 <= 6.312
```

In R you could do e.g.

```
> m2 <- seq(5.0,6.312,length.out = 10)
> m1 <- m2 + 1.188
> cbind(m1,m2)
            m1       m2
 [1,] 6.188000 5.000000
 [2,] 6.333778 5.145778
 [3,] 6.479556 5.291556
 [4,] 6.625333 5.437333
 [5,] 6.771111 5.583111
 [6,] 6.916889 5.728889
 [7,] 7.062667 5.874667
 [8,] 7.208444 6.020444
 [9,] 7.354222 6.166222
[10,] 7.500000 6.312000
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll attempt some data visualization to see if the points in comments can be clarified:

```
> d = .99; sd = 1.2; png();   plot(x=seq(-10,10), -10:10 )
> abline(h= c( 5+(.1*5), 5+(.5*5) ))
> abline(v=c(5+(.1*5) , 5+(.5*5)))
```

[image]

(I do know this is not an answer .. feel free to downvote or throw tomatoes. I won't care.)